# PHP calling diff with two strings

Tags: php, bash, diff

I'm able to call `diff` via `exec()` just fine with files, like so:

```
exec('diff -N -u '.escapeshellarg($oldfile).' '.escapeshellarg($newfile), $lines);
```

However, attempting to do this with arbitrary strings fails:

```
exec('diff -N -u <(echo '.escapeshellarg($oldstring).') <(echo '.escapeshellarg($newstring).')', $lines);
```

If I copy the command being run into bash, it works just fine. But when run in PHP I get no output. Even `2>&1` doesn't yield anything. Capturing the status code yields `1`, which should indicate that `diff` found differences, but I still get `1` even in the case where `$newstring === $oldstring`.

So I'm not quite sure what's going on. I can only assume that, for some reason, `exec` doesn't like process substitutions? Any ideas?

Comment: `exec` runs the command with `sh`, which does not support process substitution. You'd need to run it with `bash`

Comment: @thatotherguy Good point, although `exec('echo $SHELL');` yields `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Interesting - I tried wrapping the whole thing in `'/bin/bash -c '.escapeshellarg('diff ...')` and suddenly it's working. That leaves more questions (like why `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`) but at least it works!

Comment: `$SHELL` is not the currently running shell. It's the user's login shell, similar to how `$EDITOR` is the user's editor and `$PAGER` is their preferred pager.

Comment: @thatotherguy All righty, fair enough. I got it working thanks to your comment, so feel free to post as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `exec` runs the command with `/bin/sh`, which does not support process substitution (even when `sh` is provided by `bash`).

You can instead run your command explicitly with `bash -c`.

Sadly, PHP has no convenience functions for safe and robust `execv` style execution, so the easiest way to do that to build your `diff` command and then escape the whole thing:

```
exec('bash -c ' . escapeshellarg('diff -N -u <(echo '.escapeshellarg($oldstring).') <(echo '.escapeshellarg($newstring).')'), $lines);
```

Comment: Thank you. As it turns out, it doesn't like longer strings anyway (worked in testing, then tried with an 80Kb string and it died spectacularly XD) so I wound up going with temporary files and back to `sh`.

Comment: Yep yep.. The limit is OS dependent but usually  128k-256k.

Answer (score 0):

What shell is being used? Make sure diff is in the $PATH, otherwise command will fail.